# Calculation weekly quantities based on monthly data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been struggling to solve an issue to calculate monthly packages sales based on purchases during defined weekly time ranges. I have the following sample data:

**Original Data :**

[image: Original Data]

The sales quantities are for two products A and B combined. A buyer X purchases 5 B packages on the first week of every month, another 4 on week 6 then 4 packages every 10 weeks.
I added the highlighted columns to the original table. I tried the following but the calculation I made in column E seems to be the sum of sales for B packages from the actual month until the end of the year rather than only for the current month. The formula I used in cell `D2: '=(C2-6)/10'`, i.e. calculating how many 10-week ranges during the year after deducting 6 weeks. The formula I used in cell `E2: '=5+4+4*D2'`, i.e. 5 is the initial quantity in week 1, 4 is the quantity in week 6 then 4 times the amount of 10-week ranges.

**Calculation** :

[image: Calculation]

Is there a way, or a formula to calculate the monthly sales quantity for product B only?

Comment: Reverse the `C` column into 'weeks elapsed this year'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I design from scracth the table to reflect the model I have understand:

[image: Table which models the problem]

Column D is for sales the first week of the month, column E is for sale on week 10 and column F is for sales every 10 weeks.

Formulas are spanish but are easy:
mes stands for month
si stands for if
residuo stands for residual
suma stands for add

It's quite complex and there are many many criterion when we try convert weekly sales in monthly sales. My criterion was every day of a week computes to the month of the Monday of that week.

I hope have met your requirements.

Comment: Many thanks Edu for your efforts, this is helpful. This is complex indeed! Working on it now, trying to match your model with the data I have but still some challenges.

Comment: @Peter_07, you'e welcome. Don't hesitate ask again to go deeper.

Comment: thanks again. I just posted a new question, following the same subject in case you can quickly spot the correct formulas: stackoverflow.com/questions/69353877/flagging-based-specific-ranges

Comment: @Peter_07 I checked the other question, I don't own reputation to place comment there, It's simpler keep an auxiliay table like proposed solution than make a complex formula to activate the flags. Good luck!